# dropboxd Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Tags: linux, terminal, ubuntu-12.04, dropbox

I am trying to install dropbox(**x86_64 version**) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS,
with this installation guide:

http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/install-dropbox-in-an-entirely-text-based-linux-environment

But when i get to step 6. Run dropboxd

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

I get the error:

```
/home/jacob/.dropbox-dist/dropbox: 1: /home/jacob/.dropbox-dist/dropbox: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

What is causing this error? I'm not a bash expert but this seems valid to me:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Copyright 2008-2013 Dropbox, Inc.
#
# Environment script for the dropbox executable.
PAR=$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")
OLD_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export OLD_LD_LIBRARY_PATH
exec "$PAR"/dropbox "$@"
```

**Sys info:**

Linux 12.04 Ubuntu LTS
ppc64
Linux dev 3.2.0-55-powerpc64-smp #85-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 2 15:28:59 UTC 2013 ppc64 ppc64 ppc64 GNU/Linux

I would greatly appreciate any help,
Thanks

Comment: I am sorry, but how did you conclude it is related to python?

Comment: oh..i am sorry i edited my post

Comment: This really belongs on SuperUser.